# Using command line arguments to find min, max

Tags: c

I am a bit confused on how to implement this. All the functions return floats, yet the array is of type `char`. The goal is to find `min1`, `min2`, `max1`, `max2` using input from the command line. Any advice would be most helpful. Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

float min(int total, char *data[total]);
float min2(int total, char *data[total]);
float max(int total, char *data[total]);
float max2(int total, char *data[total]);
void sum_avg(int total, char *data[total], float *sum, float *average);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {  
    float sum, average; 

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        printf("\n%d-%s", i, argv[i]);
    }
    puts("");

    if (argc == 1)
        printf("You must enter at least one number\n");
    else
        printf("Total numbers entered %d\n", (argc - 1));

    min(argc, &argv[argc]);
    min2(argc, &argv[argc]);
    max(argc, &argv[argc]);
    max2(argc, &argv[argc]);
    sum_avg(argc, &argv[argc], &sum, &average);

    return 0;
}

float min(int total, char *data[total]) {
    int i;
    float min;

    return min;
}

float min2(int total, char *data[total]) {
    float min2;
    return min2;
}
```

Comment: What are min1. min2, max1 and max2?

Comment: use `sscanf`  like `sscanf(data[i], "%f", min)`. This would convert the string (char array) to float. Of course assumming it is in the correct form. Example: https://onlinegdb.com/BkJOn9qLU

Answer (score 0):

Function to find minimum could look like this:

```
float min1(int total, char *data[total])
{
   int i;
   float min = atof(data[1]);
   for (int i = 2; i < total; i++) {
     float temp = atof (argv[i]);
     if (temp < min) min = temp;
 }
   return min;
}
```

Call this funcition like this:

```
float x = min1(argc, argv);
printf("miniumum: %f\n", x);
```

Comment: Also document that the calling code should be `min(argc, argv);` instead of  `min(argc, &argv[argc]);`

Comment: Min1 is supposed to be lowest and min2 is supposed to be the second lowest

Comment: @Fizzle007: in `1 1 2`, what is the second lowest? `1` or `2`?

Comment: I was merely suggesting the OP that it is important to precisely specify the problem.

Comment: He doesn't specify in the directions. I would say 1 would be the lowest then 2 the second. His directions always leave stuff out and my emails never get answered

Comment: @chqrlieforyellowblockquotes `atof` is from `#include <stdlib.h>`. I added an example call as you suggested.

Comment: Dont worry about it. I can take it from here. Thanks so much

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I just wanted to help and don't have enough reputation to write comments :).